# D3 Sankey Node Width

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to JavaScript and not sure how to write this into a loop. How do I change the node width in the D3 library for Sankey diagrams so that it is not one constant value and instead updates based on the node names?

For example, I have this data:

```
"nodes": [
  {"name":"A" },
  {"name":"B" },
  {"name":"C" }
],
```

And I want the node width of A=10, B=20, C=30.

Here is the relevant code from https://bl.ocks.org/tomshanley.

```
var sankey = d3.sankeyCircular()
 .nodeWidth(10)
  .nodePadding(40) //note that this will be overridden by nodePaddingRatio
  .nodePaddingRatio(0.15)
  .size([width, height])
  .nodeId(function (d) {
    return d.name;
  })
  .nodeAlign(d3.sankeyJustify)
  .iterations(42)
  .circularLinkGap(3);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To respect the data-driven approach it would be better to have the width inside your data array:

```
"nodes": [ {"name":"A", "width": 10 }, ...]
```

Then it will become:

```
.nodeWidth(d => d.width)
```

Otherwise you will need a way to map the name to the width, e.g. with:

```
var nameToWidth = {"A": 10, ...};
```

Then it will become:

```
.nodeWidth(d => nameToWidth[d.name])
```

Comment: Yes, it doesn't seem like the answer above will work...